not being able to use storageState in playwright when navigation the website
I am trying to use playwright setup and pre-authenticated users to run few tests, yet I faced an issue when the storage file is set but not being used by playwright, here is the codes that I used:
auth.setup.ts
import { test as setup, expect } from "@playwright/test";
import * as path from "path";
import fs from "fs";
import { loginAsAdmin } from "./utils";
const authFile = path.join(__dirname, "playwright", ".auth", "user.json");
console.log(`Auth file setup: ${authFile}`);

setup("Authenticate/Login", async ({ page }) => {
  await loginAsAdmin(page); // login logic
  await page.context().storageState({ path: authFile });
  console.log(`Storage state saved to: ${authFile}`);
});


playwright.config.ts
import { defineConfig, devices } from "@playwright/test";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import * as path from "path";

// check if the current directry is

const directory = path.join(__dirname, "tests");
const authFile = path.join(directory, "playwright", ".auth", "user.json");

/**
 * Read environment variables from file.
 * https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv
 */
require("dotenv").config();
dotenv.config({
  path: __dirname + "\\.env",
});

/**
 * See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration.
 */
export default defineConfig({
  testDir: "./tests",
  /* Run tests in files in parallel */
  fullyParallel: true,
  /* Fail the build on CI if you accidentally left test.only in the source code. */
  forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,
  /* Retry on CI only */
  retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 0,
  /* Opt out of parallel tests on CI. */
  workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,
  /* Reporter to use. See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-reporters */
  reporter: "html",
  /* Shared settings for all the projects below. See https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions. */
  use: {
    /* Base URL to use in actions like `await page.goto('/')`. */
    baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:3000",

    /* Collect trace when retrying the failed test. See https://playwright.dev/docs/trace-viewer */
    trace: "on-first-retry",
  },

  /* Configure projects for major browsers */
  projects: [
    { name: "setup", testMatch: /.*\.setup\.ts/ },
    {
      name: "chromium",
      use: {
        ...devices["Desktop Chrome"],
        storageState: authFile,
      },
      dependencies: ["setup"],
    },   
  ],

  /* Run your local dev server before starting the tests */
  webServer: {
    command: "pnpm run dev",
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
    reuseExistingServer: !process.env.CI,
  },
});

my test example:
await page.goto("http://localhost:3000/en/profile");

When I go to the profile page, it's showing me unauthenticated state.
I am sure that the authfile exists and the setup + config file paths are similar.

The issue was that the auth.setup.js is using the next code:
page.goto("/login") and the code that I used is using the next syntax: await page.goto("http://localhost:3000/en/profile"); by doing this the auth.setup.js was going to the http://127.0.0.1:3000 url instead of the localhost which is detected as different website by the browser.
the solution was to either set all the links to: localhost or use the page.goto() function without setting the domain.
